# CSRF verification failed despite {% csrf_token %}

Tags: django

I get CSRF verification failed despite the fact that I am using  {% csrf_token %}. Where is mistake?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" name="add" value="add">
      {% for a in comments %}
      <h3>{{ a.body}}</h3>
      <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
      <input type="hidden" name="idcomment" id="{{a.id}}" value="{{a.id}}"/>
      {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`?

Comment: Also, what method are you using for rendering in your view? `render_to_response` or `render`

Comment: Yes, I have this in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Comment: You need to show the code for your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" name="add" value="add">
      {% for a in comments %}
      <h3>{{ a.body}}</h3>
      <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
      <input type="hidden" name="idcomment" id="{{a.id}}" value="{{a.id}}"/>
      {% endfor %}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Another solution

```
from django.shortcuts import render

#your view
context = {}
return render(request, 'your_file.html', contest)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop renders many `</form>` tags and `csrf` tokens as it closes outside the `form` while starting within.