# Django 1.11 - CSRF Verification failed despite having csrf_token template tag

Tags: python, django

New to django, making a to-do list page. I get the CSRF error after entering text in the input text box and hitting ENTER. I know this is likely a duplicate but after reading many of the forums and docs I'm still getting this issue. Here's what I've tried:

I have the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag inside my form tag.

I have `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in the `MIDDLEWARE` section of my settings.

`CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False` is the default in Django 1.11. I am using http, not https.

I'm using the `render()` function in my view.

My Firefox Privacy settings are set to allow third-party cookies. Doesn't work in Chrome either.

I'm not using the `enctype="text/plain"` tag in my HTML `form` tag.

I've tried supplying a [context dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846541/csrf-verification-failed-despite-csrf-token) to abide by this excerpt of the [release](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/):

[image]

Here is my code:

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To-do List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>To-do List</h1>
        <form method="POST"> <!--tried adding action="" as well-->
            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do list item" />
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
        <table id="id_table">
            <tr><td>{{ new_item_text }}</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from lists import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home_page, name='home')
]
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from lists.models import Item

def home_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['item_text'])
        return redirect('/')

    items = Item.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'lists/home.html', {'items': items}, {})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default='')
```

Comment: Your code seems to be ok...a recomendation is use forms.py to validate your POST values.

Comment: use  `csrf_exempt()` decorator on the view , so it works without csrf token. Please note that this is highly unsafe, and dont use this in a production environment. Since you are stuck this might help you. This is a temporary solution

Comment: If you got to Developer Tools in your browser and check headers of your GET and POST requests, is `csrftoken` in `Cookie: token=<csrf_token>` the same? It should be the same. If it's not the same, then the session changes between requests. It shouldn't change.

Comment: What does the actual error message say? It should tell you why the CSRF check failed. Also, probably unrelated to your issue, but the 4th argument to `render()` in 1.11 is `content_type`, you should not pass a dict there. In most cases you can just leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the csrf token direct without using a template tag

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render


def home_page(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['item_text'])
        return redirect('/')

    items = Item.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'lists/home.html', {'items': items, 
                                               'csrf':c})
```

On your template tag simply use

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='{{csrf}}' />
```

Comment: I must mention that this obsolete. you should use the csrf template tag but this is an old way to get around.